# Why in many cases, the translation inverts the future with the past (for example in Deuteronomy 34)?

Tags: translation-philosophy, deuteronomy

I perceived during the reading of this week's Torah parashah (*Deutornomy/Devariam 34:6*) that the verb in יִּקְבֹּ֨ר is in the future:

> ## וַיִּקְבֹּ֨ר אֹת֤וֹ בַגַּי֙ בְּאֶ֣רֶץ מוֹאָ֔ב מ֖וּל בֵּ֣ית פְּע֑וֹר וְלֹֽא־יָדַ֥ע אִישׁ֙ אֶת־קְבֻ֣רָת֔וֹ עַ֖ד הַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּֽה:

However in the translation it appears as the following:

> And He **buried** him in the valley, in the land of Moab, opposite Beth
> Pe'or. And no person knows the place of his burial, unto this day.

As we see in bold, **buried** is in the past, not in future as it was written in hebrew. How to deal with it?

Comment: I presume that I need not advice that Hebrew verbs do NOT have tense but only aspect.  Further, while qal imperfect is often translated as future tense, it does not have to be - this is one of those many cases where it cannot be translated as future tense.

Answer (score 1):

The word for burying (וַיִּקְבֹּ֨ר) is an imperfect. But, with special pointing, it becomes a *"waw consecutive imperfect."*  A w.c.imf. inverts the normal aspect/tense of the verb (from future to past).

How do you know when it's a w.c.imf.?  It has a waw + patach (vowel) + dagesh forte.  Without this pattern it's just a plain old imperfect.

I learned this as a "Waw consecutive imperfect."  Other grammarians refer to it as converted imperfect or inverted future.  Cf. JM:

> § 47. Inverted Future וַיִּקְטֹל
>
> 47a   The inverted future, e.g. וַיִּקְטֹל and he killed, has a strong
> Waw, that is to say, a Waw which has vowel a that adds some force
> (like that of the definite article [§ 35 b] and that of the
> interrogative pronoun מה [§ 37 c]) to the following consonant, which,
> as a consequence, is doubled. The doubling is omitted in, e.g.
> וַיְקַטֵּל (§ 18 m)1.
>
> With the Waw inversive the verb form undergoes two changes in
> accordance with the phonetic laws: 1) the final vowel reflects earlier
> shortening as in the jussive (§ 46 a); 2) the stress falls on the
> penultimate syllable, and as a consequence, the post-stress, ultima
> vowel becomes short2.
>
> (Paul Joüon and T. Muraoka, A Grammar of Biblical Hebrew, vol. 27 of
> Subsidia biblica. Accordance electronic ed. (Roma: Pontificio istituto
> biblico, 2006), 128-129.)

Comment: Can you give me one example of this usage  waw + patach (vowel) + dagesh forte?

Comment: there are many, many examples of this. e.g.: ”וְיַעֲקֹ֖ב הָלַ֣ךְ לְדַרְכּ֑וֹ וַיִּפְגְּעוּ־ב֖וֹ מַלְאֲכֵ֥י אֱלֹהִֽים׃“ (Genesis 32:2 HMT-W4). Here, note the w.c.imf. use with פָּגַע. They met him.